# Library component throw error as `lib-ibo-header' is not a known element`

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-library

I have created a angular library. after I create here is my library module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IBOLibraryComponent } from './ibo-library.component';
import { IboHeaderComponent } from './ibo-header/ibo-header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [IBOLibraryComponent, IboHeaderComponent],
  imports: [],
    exports: [IBOLibraryComponent, IboHeaderComponent]
})
export class IBOLibraryModule { }
```

here is my `public-api` :

```
export * from './lib/ibo-library.service';
export * from './lib/ibo-library.component';
export * from './lib/ibo-header/ibo-header.component';
export * from './lib/ibo-library.module';
```

After I packed this using by `yarn-pack` - which producers the `tgz` file.
But when i start to import in to other app, `ibo-library.component` - selector is works. But `ibo-header.component` selector not works.

throws the error as :

```
1. If 'lib-ibo-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'lib-ibo-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<lib-ibo-header></lib-ibo-header>"):
```

What i miss here. any one help me please?

Note: I created the `ibo-header.component` by running the command as `ng g c ibo-header` - in the module folder, is it require to update in upwards?

**UPDATE**

this is come only when i install the library by running the command as:

`yarn add ./../IBO-Library/dist/ibo-lib/ibo-lib-v0.0.1.tgz`

in case if I install like:
`yarn add ./../IBO-Library` - it works fine.

to handle `ibo-lib-v0.0.1.tgz` - requires any special command or installation?

Comment: Have you created both the components before you packed the library?

Comment: Yes, I did it before I pack it, Is any angular 8 changes on library?

Comment: I think everything is perfect, just try to repack it using "ng build <library-name>".

Comment: sure will do, do you have any idea for cli command for generate component under the library name?

Comment: Yes, sure "ng g c <component-name> --project=<library-name>"

Comment: whatever I create myself it not working other than auto generated. seems like the way i do is wrong.. let me use your command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202419/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-ashish-sharma).